# Multiple or statements always using the first one

Tags: python, if-statement

Help, whenever I type in an more than one or statements in a program, it will only run the first line of them, what is the problem?

```
if foo == "ADMIN" or "1":
    os.system("cls")
    global CODES
    CODES = "BLUE"
    PORTABLENESS()
elif foo == "IT" or "2":
    os.system("cls")
    global CODE
    CODES = "Green"
    PORTABLENESS()
elif foo == "STUDENT" or "3":
    CODE = "STUDENT"
    PORTABLENESS()
```

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
if foo == "ADMIN" or "1":
```

to

```
if foo == "ADMIN" or foo == "1":
```

and so on..

The issue is,

```
if foo == "ADMIN" or "1":
```

is evaluated as

```
if (foo == "ADMIN") or "1":
```

where `or "1"`  will *always* evaluate to `True`. Hence the issue.

Another alternative would be:

```
if foo in ("ADMIN", "1"):
```

Comment: Oh, I should have known that. Thanks!

Comment: Great. .Do mark the answer as accepted if it was useful.